# How change the name of an object with a for loop vba?

Tags: vba, visio

I would like to import multiple pictures with a for loop using a table in vba, but I have a problem with the named object. I don't konw how to deal with it (lake of experience):

```
Public Table_glob(1) As Variant



Sub Table_glob()
    table(0) = "toto"
    table(1) = "tata"

End Sub



Sub Insert()
    
    Call Table_glob
    
    For i = LBound(table) To UBound(table)
       Set shp_ & table(i) & = ActivePage.Import("C:\Users\antho\Documents\" & table(i) &".png")
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I have an error message : "expected: =" on the first "&"

Comment: You can't "create" a variable like this. What is your end goal?

Comment: I have python habits and I just got into vba so it's a shock lol...I need to import specific pictures with specific coordinates (X, Y) in MS Visio

Comment: You could possibly add each picture to a `Collection`, creating a unique key for each similar to what you're currently attempting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Insert()
Dim table(0 To 1) As Variant
Dim shp_table(0 To 1) As Variant

table(0) = "toto"
table(1) = "tata"

For i = LBound(table) To UBound(table)
Set shp_table(i) = ActivePage.Import("C:\Users\antho\Documents\" & table(i) & ".png")
Next i

End Sub
```